# chrono partially not supported in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk, c++-chrono

I'm trying to use chrono with the Android NDK. I had some success so far but some features are not supported. 
I added this line in my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++11
```

My Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

**The first problem is that steady_clock is not defined**. This line:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

generates this compile error:

```
error: 'std::chrono::steady_clock' has not been declared
```

I found out I can use monotonic_clock instead and it works, but this type is supposed to have been replaced by steady_clock.

**The second problem is that the property is_steady is not defined for any type**:

```
LOGD("high_resolution_clock is steady: ", std::chrono::monotonic_clock::is_steady);
```

generates this compile error:

```
error: 'is_steady' is not a member of 'std::chrono::monotonic_clock'
```

Does someone know if there is full support for chrono in the NDK? **I also would like to know if it's a good idea to use c++11 with the NDK**. I'm not sure if it's stable or it's likely to change in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just found a solution. Looks like you need to tell the gcc version you are going to use (I guess it's the 4.7 by default). I just added this line in my Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

Now I can use steady_clock and is_steady.

Comment: Just fyi, late in the C++11 standardization process, `monotonic_clock` was renamed to `steady_clock` and `is_monotonic` was renamed to `is_steady`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant yes I also saw that later, thanks for pointing it out anyway :)